Unable to copy edit question link when don't have edit privilege and the suggested edits queue is full
When adding a comment to request clarification on a question from a new user I try and start the comment with "please edit the question..." where "edit" is a hyperlink to the /edit page for the question, to try and encourage the question to be updated with additional information rather than the requested information being made as a comment.
To get the edit link right-click on the edit button and select "Copy Link" in the browser.
Found with combination of:

On a site without the edit privilege.
The requested edit queue is full.

Then trying to right-click on the edit button results in the browser giving a "Copy Image Link" instead. Seen with Firefox for a question on Ask Ubuntu:

Presumably being unable to perform suggested edits due to a full queue changes the way the question is rendered to disable the edit link so can't copy the link.
By the time I wrote this meta question the Ask Ubuntu suggested edits queue was no longer full and on the the original question I can now right-click on edit and then copy the edit link.
My meta question is it considered a bug that are unable to copy the edit link in the combination that don't have edit privilege and the suggested edits queue is full?

I... Can kinda see where you're going with this, but please keep in mind that we have magic links. So, you can do [edit] in a comment and it'll redirect to editing the post you commented on. Example: [edit]

@Spevacus Thanks for the magic links, I hadn't seen that part of the help before. Feel free to make add your comment an answer which I can accept, or mark this question as a duplicate.

Part of me thinks closing as a dupe is appropriate since what you want to do can more easily be done with magic links, but the other part of me thinks that closing it isn't appropriate since you're not really asking about that, you're asking whether it's a bug that you can't copy the link to the edit button if the suggested edit queue is full, which... Eh? I guess it could be perceived that way a little bit but I don't think it was originally intended for you to be able to right click that button and copy the link that way.

Possibly I fell into the trap of a "XY problem" in that I was focusing on my incorrect attempt at a solution, rather than the actual problem which is solved by magic links.

It does make sense for the edit button / link to point to a URL, even if it's disabled. At least, that's my experience from browsing the Internet for 25 years ...
